# Continuous deployment

Tags: continuous-integration, git, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery, aws-codepipeline

I have a nodejs application using expressjs. This server is handing a website built on vuejs, an application using angular and another angular app. Everything is working and I deployed to AWS eb using a pipeline. The problem is when a website change is made I build it and commit the change to AWS code commit.

Is there a way to make this automatic?

Should I keep all projects in the same repo?

What I want is: website change -> commit -> build website only -> push to AWS.

The only solution I can think of is to rebuild the 3 projects every time.

Comment: See if this helps: https://medium.com/@taleodor/using-monorepo-do-not-rebuild-unchanged-components-in-ci-c386e7c03426

Comment: @taleodor i don't use docker

Comment: Hm, why would it matter? Docker is absolutely not required there. The idea is that you need to check your directories for changes against previous state.

Comment: "Is there a way to make this automatic?" Not quite sure what part isn't automatic yet. You mean the actual build & deploy steps aren't automatic?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding a job that checks changes in the latest commit and build only that service where some files have been changed.

Comment: can you post a code snippet ?